# Having trouble understanding why this code does what it does

Tags: java

```
int x = 0;
boolean b = true;
int[] nums = { 3, 1, 3, 1, 3 };
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
    if (nums[i] == 3 && nums[i + 1] == 3)
        b = false;
    if (nums[i] == 3)
        x++;
}
if (nums[nums.length - 2] != 3 && nums[nums.length - 1] == 3)
    x++;
System.out.print(x == 3 && b);
```

In this code, `x` gets a `++` every time the for loop finds a `3`, which gives `x` a value of `3`. by the time the loop is finished. Under the loop however, there is an if statement, that asks if the is a `!=3` at -2 and a 3 at |-1`, which is a true statement,`-2 is 1`and`-1 is 3`, then`x++`, which makes`x = 4`, so why then does it print true in the print statement if it says`x == 3 && b`if`x == 4`?

Comment: Did you write that code? (This is more a code-review question. )

Comment: I did not write it, it's example code given to us to review java

Comment: This is a good example on how to **NOT** write the code. What is `x` for?

Comment: That doesn't matter, It's how the code works and what it will output, not how to write it.

Comment: @James it does not matter only if you are a machine ;)

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Answer (score 3):

What you missed is that the loop doesn't iterate over the last element of the array, so it increments x just twice (since `if (nums[i] == 3)` is not executed for the last element of the array). Therefore x is 3 at the end (incremented twice by the loop and a third time by the last condition).

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) // the if (nums[i] == 3) condition is not
                                          // tested on the element whose index is 
                                          // nums.length - 1 (and whose value is 3) 
                                          // since i doesn't reach nums.length - 1
```

Comment: `x == 2` after the loop and it is incremented in the last IF condition. `b` value never changed as there is no `3` after `3` in the array.

Answer (score 0):

`x` does equal 3 the for loop only checks the first 4 elements of the `nums` array. If you want to to equal to 4, then change the loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (i != nums.length-1 && nums[i] == 3 && nums[i + 1] == 3)
        b = false;
    if (nums[i] == 3)
        x++;
}
```

[Run here](https://ideone.com/pGbjNe)

Comment: Why though? if i = 0 and gets a ++ every time it loops, it will stop at 4 but that would be the last number, as its 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, for the index right?

Comment: @Cybernetic: Though you are absolutely right, it's worth mentioning that making your suggested change would cause the code inside the loop to crash with an index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is the condition is the for loop is: `i < nums.length - 1` which means `i` will have values from 0 (first element) to `nums.length - 1` (second last element). As a result, it will only count 2 of the 3s in the array (it will miss out the last one) and thus x will be 2 at this stage.

Finally, the statement:

```
if (nums[nums.length - 2] != 3 && nums[nums.length - 1] == 3)
    x++;
```

Is satisfied by the array and will thus make x have a value of 3

As a result `x == 3 && b` is true

Answer (score 0):

It works that way because the loop runs and ends without running over the last index. The statement which is checked is `nums[i] == 3` and if it's true, it'll incerement `x`. However, your code runs only until the index before the last index. Meaning, it'll incerement `x` only twice.

In the end you increment `x` to `3`.

Answer (score 0):

The program iterates the array from index 0 to index (length -1), increasing the value of X for each 3 found.

Since there are not two consecutive 3 in the array, b will remain true.

It will find two 3's, so at the end of the `for` loop x will be 2.

The if statement will check if the second last (`nums.length - 2`) is not a 3 (true) and if the last one is a 3 (also true), so x goes up once more to a 3.

Then it prints true because  `x=3` and `b= true`